# Obscure Scala Error Message

Tags: scala

What's wrong with that Scala Code?

```
trait A[E]
trait B[E, F[_]] extends A[F[E]]
trait C[E]
trait D[E] extends B[E, C[E]]
```

It produces the error message "C[E] takes no type parameters, expected: one"

Is it a compiler (2.10.3) bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `D` should be defined as:

```
trait D[E] extends B[E, C]
```

The second generic argument to `B` should take a single type parameter, while `C[E]` doesn't take any.

Comment: It seems, I was too tired. Your answer is absolutly correct. So I will have to find another way to express my intension.